# Merge two tables based on intersection in Python

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have two tables A and B where

A is

[image]

and B is

[image]

I have to merge them in such a way that the new table looks like this

[image]

For the common first elements in A and B, I'm taking the weighted average of middle elements of both rows having the common first elements. For example:

A and B have 'AAA' in common, so I'll compute the middle element using (5 * 3 +  5 * 2) / (3 + 2) = 5. Hence the first row of the third table becomes 'AAA', 5, 3 + 2 = 5.

I know it can be done by iterating over all the elements if I use lists, but is there a faster way to do this?

**edit** from comments: I'm also searching for a simpler way using pandas.DataFrame

Comment: please show us what did you try and write what is the problem

Comment: What data structure are you working with? Is that `pandas.DataFrame`?

Comment: @Akavall Sorry for not being specific, I am helping out a friend. I asked about the data structure being used and it is infact a `DataFrame`. Data is being loaded from two files and after merging like I've shown above, it is dumped into a file.

Comment: I don't have any experience with DataFrames so I'll start reading about it, meanwhile if you know how to carry out this task, then please help me.

Comment: please show some effort and we can help you smoothing rough edges; you said that you know how to do this with list - why don't you show us this?
(please also see http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: Hi @m.wasowski, I couldn't format the code in this comment so here's a [link](http://ideone.com/6T40zB). I think it's quite hacky, I'll try to find a way to do it using DataFrames but if you already know one, can you help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest pure python solution would be to use dictionary-like data structure, with keys being your labels, and values pairs (value = quantity * weight, quantity):

```
from collections import defaultdict
A = [
    ('A', 5, 3),
    ('B', 6, 1),
    ('D', 10, 2),
    ('C', 2, 4),
]

B = [
    ('A', 5, 5),
    ('D', 2, 1),
    ('B', 5, 4),
]

# we need to calculate (value, quantity) for each label:
a = {key: [weight * quantity, quantity] for key, weight, quantity in A}
b = {key: [weight * quantity, quantity] for key, weight, quantity in B}

# defaultdict is a dictionary like structure, but able to create 
# a new item if key is not found, in our case a new [0, 0] list:
merged = defaultdict(lambda: list((0, 0)))

# let's sum quantities and 
for key, pair in a.items() + b.items():
    # add both value and quantity respectively
    quantity, value = map(sum, zip(merged[key], pair))
    merged[key] = [quantity, value]

# now let's calculate means
for key, (quantity, value) in merged.items():
    mean = quantity / float(value)
    merged[key] = [mean, value]


for item in merged.items():
    print item
```

And even simplier it is using `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd

# first let's create dataframes
colnames = 'label weight quantity'.split()
A = pd.DataFrame.from_records([
        ('A', 5, 3),
        ('B', 6, 1),
        ('D', 10, 2),
        ('C', 2, 4),
    ], columns=colnames)

B = pd.DataFrame.from_records([
        ('A', 5, 2),
        ('D', 2, 1),
        ('B', 5, 4),
    ], columns=colnames)

# we can just concatenate those DataFrames and do calculation:
df = pd.concat([A, B])
df['value'] = df.weight * df.quantity

# sum each group with the same label
df = df.groupby('label').sum()
del df['weight']  # it got messed up anyway and we don't need it

# and calculate means:
df['mean'] = df.value / df.quantity

print df
print(df[['mean', 'quantity']])
#            mean  quantity
# label
# A      5.000000         5
# B      5.200000         5
# C      2.000000         4
# D      7.333333         3
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I'm also searching for a simpler way using `pandas.DataFrame`, will post if I find something.

Comment: if it solves your problem, you can +1 and accept the answer

Comment: Thanks for the detailed `pandas` answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can do better than this, but here is a `pandas` solution

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
In [2]: import numpy as np
In [3]: df1 = pd.DataFrame({'AAA':np.array([5,3]),'BBB':np.array([6,1]),
 .....: 'DDD':np.array([10,2]),'CCC':np.array([2,4])})
In [4]: df2 = pd.DataFrame({'AAA':np.array([5,2]),'DDD':np.array([2,1]),
 .....: 'BBB':np.array([5,4])})
In [5]: df = pd.concat([df1,df2])
In [6]: df.transpose()
      0  1   0   1
AAA   5  3   5   2
BBB   6  1   5   4 
CCC   2  4 NaN NaN
DDD  10  2   2   1
In [7]: vals = np.nan_to_num(df.values)
In [8]: _mean = (vals[0,:]*vals[1,:]+vals[2,:]*vals[3,:])/(vals[1,:]+vals[3,:])
In [9]: _sum = (vals[1,:]+vals[3,:])
In [10]: result = pd.DataFrame(columns = df.columns,data = [_mean,_sum], index=['mean','sum'])
In [11]: result.transpose()
         mean  sum
AAA  5.000000    5
BBB  5.200000    5
CCC  2.000000    4
DDD  7.333333    3
```

It probably isn't the most elegant solution, but gets the job done.